# Change width of the components in React Slick slider

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I want to set a fixed width to the components in react slick slider with some spacing in between them. Is there any way to achieve this? Also my browser shows ugly horizontal scrollbar. How to remove it?

```
import styles from "./styles.module.css";

import Head from "next/head";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default function quickGuide() {
  const settings = {
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };
  return (
    <>
     
      <div
        className={`flex items-center w-[100vw] h-[90vh] ${styles.carouselContainer}`}
      >
        <div className={`w-[90vw] mx-auto text-white`}>
          <Slider {...settings}>
            <div>
              <img src={"/assets/slides/Slide-1.png"} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={"/assets/slides/Slide-2.png"} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={"/assets/slides/Slide-3.png"} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={"/assets/slides/Slide-4.png"} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src={"/assets/slides/Slide-5.png"} />
            </div>
          </Slider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

It looks like this at the moment
[Output in the browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5WEk.png)